# Can any Java based templating engine work with Websphere Commerce?

Tags: java, templating-engine, websphere-commerce

I'm a UX developer at a retail company, we use Websphere Commerce for our e-com sites. The app dev guys are in complete control of the HTML output we have to file bugs with them to get something as simple as an ID changed in HTML. HTML and front end performance isn't their specialty and things get implemented poorly because of the situation. The whole situation is extremely inefficient so I'm working up a proposal to implement a templating engine on our platform so that we can fix this situation and everyone can work in their respective wheelhouses. I've seen some suggestions for Java based templating engines such as StringTemplate or FreeMarker. Knowing little of Java application development and the Websphere Commerce framework can any Java based templating engine work with Websphere Commerce? If not are there any recommendations on Websphere Commerce specific templating engines?

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare, I'm not familiar with Websphere Commerce, but I'd recomend FreeMarker. We use it, and I think it rocks. http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_quickstart.html

Comment: Freemarker or Velocity would be ideal

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) (which is now separated from Struts) should be a possibility. For more info see:

[Using Struts Tiles with WebSphere Commerce Category and Product Display command](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?q1=COM&rs=463&uid=swg21328797&context=SSGJWE&cs=utf-8&lang=en&loc=en_US)

Comment: Supposedly FreeMarker can be integrated with Tiles. I would be interested to hear if anyone has done this within a WebSphere Commerce environment.

http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/integration/freemarker.html

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't developed in Websphere Commerce, I think you have JSF in Websphere Commerce. So you should be able to add Facelets.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/

Answer (score 0):

What version of Commerce are you using? You should be able to use eSpots and provide whatever content/html you want within those spots. I actually created a YouTube video on eSpots - you can check them out here - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zngS5Zv33vw&list=UU_XKh8vvQlKnaScxFgjtq3w&index=11&feature=plcp

The video shows how to use precision marketing with eSpots but you can define whatever content you want within an eSpot.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of stuff out there already that is preintegrated with Websphere Commerce like Coremedia and e-Spirit.